# How to use pointer-to-pointer's variables?

Tags: c++, element, pointer-to-pointer

I am trying this code:

```
int x[] = {1,5};
int y[] = {3,6};
int *w[] = {x,y};
int **z = w;


printf("%d", **z[1]);
cout<<**z[0];
```

But it doesn't work. My goal is to access to each element inside the x or y arrays. My question comes from this part of a really OpenCV code:

```
float h_ranges[] = {0, 180}; 
float s_ranges[] = {0, 256};
const float* ranges[] = {h_ranges, s_ranges};
```

And like to know how is it possible to read each element inside `ranges[]`?

EDIT: I tryed:

```
printf("%d", z[1][1]);
cout<<z[0][0];
```

And it worked, but it's interesting for me to know why

```
printf("%d", **z[1][1]);
cout<<**z[0][1];
```

Doesn't work, but the following code works

```
printf("%d", *w[1]);
cout<<*w[0];
```

What is the difference between `w` and `z` here?

EDIT2:

Why the result of

```
printf("%d", *w[1]);
cout<<*w[0];
```

Is same as the result of:

```
printf("%d", *z[1]);
cout<<*z[0];
```

Comment: Do you know what the type of `z[1][1]` is? If yes why do you think that adding two "stars" at the front is allowed?

Comment: @UnholySheep: Thank you! I got it!

Comment: @UnholySheep: But it is still confusing why `*w[0]` and `*z[0]` have same result? In fact I can not imagine truly the structure of `z` at this point!

Comment: @rpaulin56: So why `**z` or `*z[0][1]` don't work inside `cout` for example?

Comment: Don't write this sort of code. You don't want to be a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: **z[0] is dereferencing three times, that's why your cout does not work.

Comment: Let's recap: *x is another way of writing x[0], so **z is like z[0][0].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why `z[1][1]` works?

`z` is a pointer to pointer to `int` in `w` array. Dereferencing `*z` will give you pointer to the 1st `int` in `{1,5}` and dereferincing it once more `**z` will give you that `int`, which is `1`. This is identical to doing `z[0][0]` or `*(*(z + 0) + 0)`.

`z[1][1]` is the same as `*(*(z + 1) + 1)`. Dereferencing `*(z + 1)` will give you the pointer to the first `int` in the second array `{3,6}`. Incrementing `*(z + 1) + 1` will give you the pointer to the second `int` in the second array `{3,6}`, Dereferencing `*(*(z + 1) + 1)` will give you the actual second `int` of the second array `{3,6}`, which in your case is `6`;

> Why `**z[1][1]` doesn't work?

With `z[1][1]` will get you an `int` (see above), `6` in your example. So what happens when you try to dereference an `int`, let alone twice? An error!

> Why `*w[1]` works?

`w` is array of pointers. With `w[1]` you get the second pointer from that array which points to the array of 2 `int`s, `{3,6}`. If you dereference it, you will get the 1st `int` of that array, which in your case is `3`.

> Why the result of `*w[1]` is same as the result of `*z[1]`?

Let's visualize it:

```
{1,5} {3,6}
 |     |
{w[0], w[1]}
 |     | 
 z     z+1
```

Array `w` is array of 2 pointers to `int`, which are `w[0]` and `w[1]`. `w[1]` is the second pointer to `int` in that array. The `int` it points to is `3`. `z` is a pointer to pointer to `int`, or in this case pointer to `w[0]`, which is pointer to `1`. `z[1]` is the same as `*(z+1)` and it makes `z` to point to the next pointer before dereferencing result, which in this case is `w[1]`, which points to `3`. Dereferencing both `w[1]` and `z[1]` yields the same result, because ultimately they both point to the same `int`, which is `3`.

Comment: Thank you very much! But may you explain more about `*(*(z + 0) + 0)`. What is exactly meaning of `z+0` or `z+1` ? What is the `z` in this point that you `+1` it? I think `z` is an address and you step to next address by `+1`.

Comment: I also added a new question (EDIT 2) to my previous questions, that is vague for me!

Comment: @Hasani I have added a little visualisation. I'm afraid if you have any more questions after that you will have to post a new question.